# What is the use/structure/meaning of 'had it not [something], ...'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I encountered a question in an exam and I am wondering about the exact answer and reasons behind it

**Question:**

Had it not rained, the farmers _________ all of their crops.

A. Would lose
B. Should lose
C. Should have lost
D. Could have lost

Your explanations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Had it not rained..." = "If it hadn't rained..." = "Had it not been for the rain..."*

> your answer is: "...the farmers **could have lost** all of their crops." ("would have lost" would also be correct.)

There must be agreement between "condition" and "consequence".

> If she phones me, I will tell her.  (presente simple requires future simple)
>
> If she phoned me, I would tell her. (past simple requires conditional simple)
>
> If she had phoned me, I would have told her. (past perfect requires conditional perfect)

Answer (score 1):

Had it not rained = If it had not rained => Were it not for the rain ...